# Changing a Macros in another C++ file

Tags: c++, macros, include

I have a C++ file that uses functions defined in another C++ file.
Let's say I am working with main.cpp and func.cpp.

**func.cpp**

```
#define SIZE 32

bitset<SIZE> functionA(int a)
{
    Code; 
}
```

and I have main.cpp

**main.cpp**

```
#include "func.cpp"

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    bitset<64> out;
    out = functionA(a); /// This is the functionality I want.
}
```

I don't want to directly change the value of *SIZE* in *func.cpp*. I want a way to somehow change the macros definition of *SIZE* to 64 from main.cpp. After this, I can call *functionA* and expect it to return a bitset of size 64.

Comment: "I don't want to directly change the value of SIZE" why not?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I am using func.cpp for other files too. All of them demand a value of 32 for SIZE. This was a special case where I want it to be 64. That's why I don't want to change it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the definition of `SIZE` to be used with `bitset<SIZE>` without changing `func.cpp`. It is not possible.

Do not use a macro.

Make `functionA` a function template:

```
template <size_t SIZE = 32>
bitset<SIZE> functionA(int a)
{
    Code; 
}
```

Then in `main` call it with the `SIZE` you want:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    bitset<64> out = functionA<64>(a); /// This is the functionality I want.
}
```

Because `32` is the default for `SIZE`, whenever you call `functionA(x)` the returned value is a `bitset<32>`.

Do not include source files. Source files should not be included. Instead you should compile the source files and then link them. Include a header with the function declaration.

Comment: This might offer same functionality. Thanks. But is there a way for SIZE to remain a MACROS and _functionA_  remain a function? Actually, I have other files using _functionA_ too, so this might create complications.

Comment: @Stelk what complications? Other uses of `functionA` can remain unchanged

Comment: @Stelk the differene is that now you cannot get function pointers to `functionA` anymore. Are you using function pointers?

Comment: I actually just moved from C to C++, so I don't exactly have knowledge about templates. I might be persistent but is there a way to remain fucntionA a function and SIZE a Macros defination?

Comment: @Stelk Macros for the purposes of holding constant values are largely an anti-pattern in C++ unless it's strictly needed by the preprocessor. Macros violate scope and can be better represented in other ways (e.g. `constexpr` constants). But even then, you aren't even wanting this as a constant -- so macros are _not the right tool for this job_. This is exactly the reason why function templates exist.

Comment: @Stelk no. you cannot change `SIZE` to be used with `functionA` without modifiying `func.cpp`.